# How to user input a pattern in string at a time and store it as a 2d character array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am stuck with a particular problem. Any help would be highly appreciable .

Suppose i am given rows=8 and column=5. How do i take a input from the user in the following manner.

```
Aacvg
Qwn&k
LOpyc
GYhcj
%&fgT
JUIOP
icgfd
Hu*hc
```

and then calculate the number of 'c' in the whole user defined pattern, which will give an output=5 here.

I tried to input each line as String and then convert it into a 2D char array but it wasn't working that way.
Also how to limit the number of char per line to the number of column(here 5).

NB:- the input will be a whole line together and then the next line as a whole .... till row=8(for this example).

I would be very thankful if someone could tell me a way to do that.(I even considered array of arrays.)

I wrote the following code but it isn't working so if anyone can write the correct way to do it.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
            String str;
            str = sc.nextLine();
            for(int j=0;j<column;j++){
                char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
                a[i][j]= charArray[j];
                if(a[i][j]=='c'){
                     count= count+1;
                }
            }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fumbling around with arrays I would recommend to make use of the functions provided by the `String` class.

This is one possible approach to achieve this with code based upon your example.

```
    int row = 8;
    int column = 5;
    int count = 0;
    char searchedCharacter = 'c';
    int currentIndex;
    boolean searching;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        str = sc.nextLine();
        currentIndex = -1;
        searching = true;

        while (searching) {
            // indexOf will return -1 if the character was not found in the String
            currentIndex = str.indexOf(searchedCharacter, currentIndex + 1);

            if (currentIndex > -1 && currentIndex < column) {
                count++;
            } else {
                searching = false;
            }
        }
    }

    sc.close();

    System.out.println(count);
```

This way you won't have to deal with an `Array` and also not with the comparison of the characters, because your `String` object will do most of the work for you.

It will also prevent you from running in an `IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions` which can easily happen in your code because you don't check if `charArray[j]` is actually a valid index.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the code you want:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WTF {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new WTF().doIt();
}

private void doIt() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int row = 8;
    int column = 5;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the row no. " + (i + 1) + ":");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        // cut the string to 5 chars
        str = str.substring(0, column);

        char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
        for (char c : charArray) {
            if ('c' == c) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The number of c entered is: " + count);
}

}
```